# How to use transaction with many queries from different Model in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, transactions, codeigniter-3

Below is the syntax from a `Model` using Codeigniter Framework. So i want to do this kind of query, i grouped many query inside another class like this, but i used this transaction outside the class like this.

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
$insert1 = $this->Actmain->tempPerwakilanToTransaksi($t_nib_kppa_temp['id_permohonan']);
$insert2 = $this->Actmain->transaksiPerwakilanToHistory($t_nib_kppa_temp['id_permohonan'],$arrData['id_history']);
if(!$insert1 || !$insert2) {
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
    return FALSE;
} else {
   $this->db->trans_commit();
   echo "Yatta desune"
}
```

I want to check if at least one query that didn't work successfully, it will rollback all the query. The problem is, it's always return `true` which came from query in variable `$insert1` or `$insert2`. It's always echo `Yatta Desune` but the insert and update query didn't executed.

What is the proper way to used db transaction in Codeigniter 3 but bunch of query executed in different Model ?

Comment: If you are not familiar with transactions we recommend you find a good online resource to learn about them for your particular database. The information below assumes you have a basic understanding of transactions.

Comment: The information below ? where @Gulshan

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html